Clear Cache React Native Programmatically
im react native dev and i have one problem about my apps, it keep slower day by day and i notice its because cache keep growing , but when i clear the cache manualy from picture below, i just click "Clear cache" (not clear storage) the lag is gone. i have been trying to search all over the library and find other reference but it still same and no solution.
my goal is i want to clear cache programmatically

my react native version : "react-native": "0.72.4"
any help or solution i will appreciate, thank you

Have you tried using react-native-fs?

import React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const App = () => {
  const handleClearCache = async () => {
    try {
      const cacheDir = RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath;
      await RNFS.unlink(cacheDir);
      console.log('Clean cache sucess!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erro clean cache:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Clean Cache" onPress={handleClearCache} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

Other example
https://github.com/mrousavy/clean-rn
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-clear-app-cache
https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs
Other example in package.json
"gradle-clean": "cd android && ./gradlew clean",

and then try typing yarn gradlew clean in the terminal

i think this one might work , but will try and let you know , thanks dev.vitor
